# Multiple VMs Accessing a single device over PCIE

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, kvm, libvirt, pci-e

I am using the libvirt/QEMU/KVM stack to run some VMs on an Ubuntu 20.04 host. I am using the virsh CLI tool for VM management. I'd like to allow multiple VMs to access the same device (FPGA) over PCIE. It seems that libvirt doesn't allow this, and when I attach the PCIE device to multiple VMs and try to power more than one on, I get the following error.

```
error: Failed to start domain ubuntu-guest-2
error: Requested operation is not valid: PCI device 0000:05:00.0 is in use by driver QEMU, domain ubuntu-guest-1
```

This kinda makes sense to me, as there shouldn't be conflicting data sent over the PCIE bus. But nonetheless, does anyone know a workaround to make this happen?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of techniques to share a device across VMs. All of them require either device-specific software support in the VMM, hardware in the device to support sharing (SR-IOV), or both (Scalable IOV).

For a custom FPGA design, you would need to provide this.

SR-IOV is part of the PCIe specification, so there may be libraries available that you could incorporate into your FPGA design.

Comment: Actually in some Xilinx systems there is already SR-IOV capability available as physical function out of the box...